# How to get dynamic taxes from location in UBER API?

Tags: uber-api

I want create a APP MOBILE and i need use a UBER API.

I need get dynamic taxes in my location.

I can find a Class or Method to get this infos in UBER API.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

please see the documentation for Uber's API at developer.uber.com. If you are asking for a dynamic location of all Uber drivers around you, that is not something available through Uber's API. Thanks.